# R and Posix: Importing times into dataframe results in lost informations

Tags: r, posix

this is my first question on Stackoverflow, so i apologize if i make any mistake..

I am trying to import a dataframe in R, which contains 3 rows, the first of which is time expressed as: "minutes:seconds,milliseconds". E.g.: "05:02,159".

Every time i try to import the time, retaining the milliseconds, the whole time seems to reset.

An example code is below, with time in the same format as it is in the dataframe:

```
> time1 <- "00:00,05"
> time1
[1] "00:00,05"
```

Above the information is correctly retained. Then i try to convert the char object into a POSIX one.

```
> time2 <- as.POSIXct(strptime(time1,"%M:%OS"))
```

When i try to visualise "time2", only the date is shown

```
> time2
[1] "2016-03-19 CET"
```

When i try to format the output, it seems that time information have been reset

```
> strftime(time2,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3')
[1] "2016-03-19 00:00:00.000"
> strftime(time2,'%H:%M:%OS3')
[1] "00:00:00.000"
```

I also tried adjusting the *options(digits.secs = 3)* settings, but nothing changed.

Comment: This probably depends on your locale; it works with a dot instead of a comma in my system’s locale (i.e. `"00:00.05"`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the comma with a dot.

```
time1 <- "00:00,05"
time2 <- as.POSIXct(strptime(gsub(",", ".", time1, fixed = TRUE),"%M:%OS"))
strftime(time2,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS4')
#[1] "2016-03-19 00:00:00.0499"
```

Note that floating point precision is relevant here.

Comment: When i imported the dataframe i correctly set the comma as the decimal separator, but this isn't relevant for *chr* objects, as the time column. Thank you!